# Returning Month Name in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

Using `SQL Server 2008`, I have a query that is used to create a view and I'm trying to display a **month's name** instead of an integer.

In my database, the `datetime` is in a column called `OrderDateTime`. The lines in the query that return the date is:

```
DATENAME(yyyy, S0.OrderDateTime) AS OrderYear,
DATEPART(MONTH, S0.OrderDateTime) AS OrderMonth
```

This returns a column of years and a column of months as integers. I want to return the month names `(Jan, Feb, etc`). I've tried:

```
CONVERT(varchar(3), DATEPART(MONTH, S0.OrderDateTime) AS OrderMonth
```

This is obviously is incorrect, as I get

> Incorrect syntax near 'AS'

message. What is the proper syntax for my query?

Comment: The incorrect syntax message is due to not closing off the final brackets before the `AS` - `CONVERT(varchar(3), DATEPART(MONTH, S0.OrderDateTime)) AS OrderMonth`

Comment: What is S0 mean in the sql query

Comment: @user7157710 S0 is the alias given to the table where the field is located.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

This will give you the full name of the month.

```
select datename(month, S0.OrderDateTime)
```

If you only want the first three letters you can use this

```
select convert(char(3), S0.OrderDateTime, 0)
```

Comment: Comment incorrectly posted in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40592863/5292302)  "What is S0 mean in the sql query?" by [user7157710](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7157710/user7157710)

Comment: S0 is an alias for a table. The answer is carrying it over from the question.

Comment: I'd like to add that, typically, you don't even want to use these functions. You're better off selecting the date as date(time) or month as integer or whatever and then let your UI take care of 'converting' it to a human-friendly month name. That way your application / UI can take care of localization rather than your database, which doesn't have the slightest clue on your user's preferences or application's settings for localization. To put it in another way, think about it like this: what if your user prefers the Chinese 二月 over february?

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried `DATENAME(MONTH, S0.OrderDateTime)` ?

Answer (score 12):

Change:

```
CONVERT(varchar(3), DATEPART(MONTH, S0.OrderDateTime) AS OrderMonth
```

To:

```
CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(MONTH, S0.OrderDateTime)) AS OrderMonth
```

Comment: I think you mean `DATENAME`. `DATEPART` wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,Getdate()),3)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @iMonth INT=12
SELECT CHOOSE(@iMonth,'JANUARY','FEBRUARY','MARCH','APRIL','MAY','JUNE','JULY','AUGUST','SEPTEMBER','OCTOBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER')
```

Answer (score 2):

Select `SUBSTRING (convert(varchar,S0.OrderDateTime,100),1,3)` from your Table Name

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012 it is possible to use `FORMAT(@mydate, 'MMMM') AS MonthName`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you what u are requesting for:

```
select convert(varchar(3),datename(month, S0.OrderDateTime))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( `col1` ) FROM `table_name`
```

Answer (score 1):

for me DATENAME was not accessable due to company restrictions.... but this worked very easy too.

```
FORMAT(date, 'MMMM') AS month
```

Answer (score 0):

Without hitting db we can fetch all months name.

```
WITH CTE_Sample1 AS
(
    Select 0 as MonthNumber

    UNION ALL

    select MonthNumber+1 FROM CTE_Sample1
        WHERE MonthNumber+1<12
)

Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , MonthNumber ,0 ) ) from CTE_Sample1
```

Answer (score 0):

basically this ...

```
declare @currentdate datetime = getdate()
select left(datename(month,DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())),3)
union all
select left(datename(month,(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()))),3)
union all
select left(datename(month,(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()))),3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT
   Format( ('YourDateColumn'),'MMM') as MonthName
  FROM YourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Format(GetDate(),'MMMM')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).