# Format date as Month dd, yyyy?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I'd like to select a date from a DateTime column in Month dd, yyyy format.

I currently am using the following code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DateColumnHere, 107) 'Formatted Date'
```

Which returns:

```
Feb 15, 2013
```

Is there any way to get the full month name, like:

```
February 15, 2013
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650830/returning-month-name-in-sql-server-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a site with a ton of formats and little date hacks for SQL:

> http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

And here is their query for your format (Month dd, yyy):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 9) AS [Month DD, YYYY]
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has a limited number of date formats, but you can use the `DATENAME` function to concatenate the peices:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + 
       DATENAME(DD, GETDATE()) + ', ' + 
       DATENAME(YYYY, GETDATE())
       AS 'Formatted Date'
```

However *in general* it's often better practice to leave dates in date format rather than converting to strings, and only converting to strings in the display layer (Web site, report, application, wherever) where the formatting capabilities are much richer.  Plus you lose the ability to do date math, sorting, etc. if you convert to string.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 9) AS [Month DD, YYYY]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 1,3,DATENAME(month,GETDATE()))
```