# Get month name from SQL Server date value in table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a statistics query (display the number of records per month).

The problem is that I want the month displayed in letter such as January, February, March, etc. not like 1, 2 or 3. I is not displaying month name in alphabet using `month(getdate()`.

I don't know how can I do the conversion. Here is my SQL Server query:

```
select count(*) [Total], month(date) [Mois] 
from user 
where year(date) >= 2018 
group by month(date) 
order by month(date) desc
```

Comment: Have a look into the thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650830/returning-month-name-in-sql-server-query

Comment: I'd like to add that, typically, you don't even want to use these functions. You're better off selecting the date as date(time) or month as integer or whatever and then let your UI take care of 'converting' it to a human-friendly month name. That way your application / UI can take care of localization rather than your database, which doesn't have the slightest clue on your user's preferences or application's settings for localization. To put it in another way, think about it like this: what if your user prefers the Chinese 二月 over february?

Comment: @Suraj Kumar : thanks for your link , it's work , i just use datename(month,date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try something like this

```
select convert(char(3), [date], 0)
select datename(month, [date])
```

Comment: And [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#year-month-and-day-datepart-arguments) for completeness

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
SELECT FORMAT ([Date], 'MMMM') as date
```

Comment: It could be an answer but FORMAT is not available in lower version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that the query that you want is:

```
select year(date), datename(month, date), count(*)  as total
from user 
where year(date) >= 2018 
group by year(date), datename(month, date)
order by min(date);
```

Notes:

- You should be including the year in your query.  Your `where` suggests that the query could return more than one year.
- Don't include year if you really want to combine months from multiple years, but I think that is unlikely.
- Generally, you want the results in chronological order.  A convenient method is to order by a `date` value in each group.